# jQuery validate method is not triggered if form is submitted for the first time

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-validate

So, I'm creating a custom plugin which uses jQuery validate as base. My idea is to create a plugin that will validate any normal form without having to create individual Jquery Validate setup for all of them. Here is my code

html

```
<form role="form" class="form-horizontal form-validate" id="" action="/action/action.users.php">
    <div class="box-body">
        <h4>Account Information</h4>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">test</label>
            <div class="col-sm-9 controls">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-12">
                        <input name="txt_username" class="form-control" placeholder="Username"  value="" type="text" data-required="true">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">test2</label>
            <div class="col-sm-9 controls">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-12">
                        <input name="txt_password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" value="" type="text" data-required="true">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="box-footer">
        <button class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" type="submit">Submit</button>
        <button class="btn btn-sm btn-warning" type="reset">Reset</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

js

```
(function ( $ ) {
    $.fn.validate_form = function(options) {
        var settings = $.extend({
                action: "/",
                redirect: "",
                notification: "",
            }, options 
        );

        var $this = this;
        var post_data = {};
        var post_response = "default";

        /* if first submit, it wont trigger this, succeeding submits, it will run this */
        $this.validate({
            submitHandler:function(){
                $this.find(':input[type="text"],:input[type="radio"],:input[type="password"],:input[type="email"]').each(function(){
                    element = $(this);
                    var name = element.attr('name');
                    var val = element.val();

                    if(element.is(':radio')) {
                        if(element.is(':checked')) 
                            post_data[name]  = val;
                    }
                    else post_data[name]  = val;
                });

                console.log(post_data);

                $.post( settings.action, post_data, function(result){
                    post_response = result;
                    console.log(result);
                });
            }
        });
        /*end if first submit, it wont trigger this */

        $this.find('[data-required="true"]').each(function(){
            $(this).rules("add",{
                required: true
            });
        }); 

        return post_response;
    }
}( jQuery ));

$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".form-validate").submit(function(e){
        var action = $(this).attr("action");
        var result = $(this).validate_form({
            action:action
        });
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

It is working, except for, if the form is submitted for the first time, the validation won't work, however, the if I submit it again, it will now work fine. I can't seem to find the problem since there is no error on firebug. Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: Before you can successfully write a plugin that will leverage the jQuery Validate plugin, you first would need to understand how the jQuery Validate plugin is supposed to be used.  In other words, you clearly do not understand that the `.validate()` method is only used to ***initialize*** the plugin.  It's not supposed to be wrapped in a `submit` handler; and that's the whole key to your problem.  I suggest that you carefully review this page:  http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jquery-validate/info

Comment: I also don't understand the point of doing all this in the first place, since the jQuery Validate plugin will automatically pick up the inline HTML attributes without your plugin.  http://jsfiddle.net/49vt4sze/

Comment: hi @Sparky, ive fixed, ive replaced submit with each, there initializing the validation automatically, as opposed validating it if the form is submitted. thanks!

Comment: Again, I don't understand the whole point of your custom plugin.  Here is the same without it:   http://jsfiddle.net/37qvg5z3/

Comment: yes @Sparky, i agree with you, but ill be using heavily customized forms (using data attrbutes) that will control the response from the server,

Comment: the plugin will also handle the ajax request from the server + custom validations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `.validate()` method is only used to ***initialize*** the plugin. It's not supposed to be wrapped in a `.submit()` handler, and that's the whole key to your problem.

Carefully review this page for basic setup & usage: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jquery-validate/info